# Need to count distinct values with a composite primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct

I have to generate a report that displays the name of different locations and the number of times unique course offerings are offered in these locations. The report needs to only indicate the city and the no. of unique course offerings and be sorted by the highest number of unique offerings.
The problem I have is the offering table has a composite primary key (offering begin date and course code)

I run this SQL query and it comes up with an error as you can't count multiple columns. But I am not sure how to split the count.

```
SELECT 
    offlocation AS city, COUNT(distinct offbegindate,crscode) as no. of unique course offerings
FROM
    offering
GROUP BY offlocation
ORDER BY COUNT(distinct offbegindate,crscode) as no. of unique course offerings DESC;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can anybody post how to achieve such thing using criteria api?

Answer (score 5):

Just minor adjustments, "Row types" for count distinct:

```
SELECT 
    offlocation AS city,
    COUNT(distinct (offbegindate,crscode)) as no_of_unique_course_offerings
FROM
    offering
GROUP BY offlocation
ORDER BY no_of_unique_course_offerings DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to concatenate values:

```
SELECT 
    offlocation AS city, COUNT(distinct offbegindate || '-' || crscode) as no. of unique course offerings
FROM
    offering
GROUP BY offlocation
ORDER BY COUNT(distinct offbegindate,crscode) as no. of unique course offerings DESC;
```

Comment: Not a very safe way. Can you concat offbegindate and crscodes? What if '-' exists in either offbegindate or crscode? E.g 'A-A' || '-' || 'B' is equal to 'A' || '-' || 'A-B'.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would work:

```
select offlocation AS city , count(*)  as cnt from
(

  select distinct offlocation,offbegindate,crscode from offering

) v 

group by city 
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: Distinct is not a function (with parameters). I.e. do "select distinct offlocation..." instead to make things clearer!

Answer (score 0):

select count(
  distinct CONCAT( offbegindate, '-' , crscode )
)
from cgtask.tsk_proj_cost;

Comment: Please explain what your code does, why OP's code is not working and why your solution will help with OP's issue.